# Why does gradient descent fail training a network for predicting times table?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am training a feedforwardnet with gradient descent `traingd` as backpropagation algorithm to predict times table.

```matlab
X = [repmat([1:10]', 10, 1) repelem([1:10]', 10)];
y = X(:, 1) .* X(:, 2);

net = feedforwardnet(8);                % Create a neural network with 8 neurons in the hidden layer
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'logsig';   % Hidden layer activation function set to logsig
net.trainFcn = 'traingd';               % Set backpropagation algorithm to gradient descent
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 0.6;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0.2;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 0.2;
[net, TR] = train(net, X', y');         % Train the network
```

But when I try to train my network it directly fails, I mean validation error keeps increasing from the start as you can see below.

[image: Validation error using traingd]

I couldn't figure out the reason so I wanted to ask it here.

When I train my network using Levenberg-Marquardt `trainlm` as backpropagation algorithm then everything works fine.

[image: Validation error using trainlm]

Comment: The error is still increasing with Epochs right? So you could say that the `traingd` gradient descent method makes the training 'unstable'. My guess is that the best performance at epoch 0 for `traingd` is caused by the fact that the `net` uses the weights trained with `trainlm` during the epoch 0. Then it tries to train with the `traingd` and fails miserably again.

Comment: Yes error keeps increasing. I do not know why gradient descent is not working here.